# JediInstaller will not run

Tags: delphi-2010, delphi-xe4, jvcl

I downlaoded newest verrsion of JVCl which include JCL

As first thing, I try in jcl folder to doubleclick install.bat

It compiles and runs but then throws error:

> Program can not start as rtl180.bpl is missing on the computer

I have Delphi 2010 installed here:
D:\DevTools\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\7.0

I have Delphi XE4 installed here:
D:\DevTools\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\11.0

I had many more installed in the past, but some were trials, some no longer work in Windows 10 etc. so I have been removing unwanted Delphi versions. But I have tried removing all traces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to fix "System environment variables - Path" with path to bpls